# Cannot run JUnit in VSCode. AssertEquals symbol not recognized

Tags: java, junit, visual-studio-code

I have seen previous problems on here addressing an issue with running junit tests on VSCode and most solutions suggest adding a JAR to the class path. I have this however when I run my test file it still does not recognize assertEquals. Can someone please explain how I have to set this up? I am trying to run some sample problems for a software course.

```
import org.junit.runner.JUnitCore;
import org.junit.runner.Result;
import org.junit.runner.notification.Failure;

public class TestGeneratePrimes {


    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Result result = JUnitCore.runClasses(TestPrimes.class);

        for(Failure failure : result.getFailures()) {

            System.out.println(failure.toString());

        }

        System.out.println(result.wasSuccessful());

    }

}
```

The code above is what I run but it tells me it does not recognize assertEquals which is being called in my TestPrimes class. I'm still very new to this so I apologize if I am not being descriptive enough. I am able to compile other java programs. I just cannot run these JUnit tests.

Comment: This is not the way to write JUnit tests.

Comment: I am calling tests I have written in separate java file.

Answer (score 1):

I think org.junit.Assert.assertEquals might have been introduced in a version of Junit jar that is not available in your environment. 
I saw a similar issue with junit-4.10 while the feature I was trying to use was only in junit-4.12.jar and up.
It's been a while and I can't be more precise but I suggest you check the junit version in your environment.

Answer (score 0):

Your environment may differ/require more configuration, but try importing Assert?

`import org.junit.Assert;`

Comment: I still get the same error. In my TestPrimes class that is being called I have the following imported:   

    import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;

    import org.junit.Test;